# Error in ajax path without 'www'

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post, path

firstly i am sorry for my bad English because i'm student right now.
Anyway my problem is as i wrote in the title. so
ajax doesn't work without "www".
let me show you.

```
var yol = "www.sinemayolu.com";
        //Arama Kısmı Anlık Ajax
    $('.searchtext').keyup(function () {
        var secilenArama = $('header div.second div.search select option:selected').text();
        var aranacak_kelime = $(this).val();
        if (aranacak_kelime.length >= 3) {
            $.post(yol + '/Anasayfa_Film_Ara.php', {
                secilenArama: secilenArama,
                aranacak_kelime: aranacak_kelime
            }, function ($ajax) {
                if (!aranacak_kelime) {
                    $('.searchResult').fadeOut();
                } else {
                    if ($ajax != 0) {
                        $('.searchResult').fadeIn();
                        $('.searchResult ul').html($ajax);
                    } else {

                        $('.searchResult').fadeIn();
                        $('.searchResult ul').html('Veri Bulunamadı.');
                    }
                }
            });
        } else if (aranacak_kelime.length <= 0) {
            $('.searchResult').fadeOut();
        } else {
            $('.searchResult').fadeIn();
            $('.searchResult ul').html('Arama Yapmak İçin En Az 3 Harf Yazmalısınız.');
        }


    });
```

Comment: Why do you expect it to work the same with different server names?

Comment: so i am trying to search without www and this doesn't work. but when i am trying with www it's working.

Comment: A URL needs to have `//` before the server name, otherwise it's just treated as a filename. So `yol` should be `//winemayoly.com` or `//www.sinemayolu.com`

Answer (score 0):

Add this in HTML `head`
`<base href="http://www.sinemayolu.com/" />`
and ajax like a boss

```
        $.post('Anasayfa_Film_Ara.php', {
```

Comment: It should be `href="//www.sinemayolu.com/". You need `//` to signify the server name.